# Надо ли выделять кавычками наименование услуги?

Tags: пунктуация, названия, кавычки

Надо ли выделять кавычками название услуги? Например, услуга "пропускной режим"?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, названия услуг нужно заключать в кавычки. Я бы писал их с прописной подобно названиям товаров, хотя в Нацкорпусе есть разные примеры:

При этом для удобства расчетов с населением реализована услуга «торговый эквайринг». [Отраслевой экспертный подход к развитию крупного и среднего бизнеса // «Эксперт», 2014]

Услуга «Умное страхование» работает на базе продукта «Мобильные сотрудники». [Реклама // «Эксперт», 2014]